# Manipulate matrix based on two threshold vectors in R

Tags: r, matrix

I don't know exactly how I should frame this problem, nor can I think of any example of how to solve it. I came up with a solution but I'm wondering if there's an easier or more efficient way of dealing with it.

I'm working with a matrix of distances between individuals and events, and I want to transform the matrix based on characteristics of the events and the individuals. In this case, I want to know if an individual was exposed to an event within certain distance based on other criteria.

Let's say we have two vectors, one of 4 individuals and another of 3 events. We obtain a matrix of the distances in km between individuals and events:

```
> dist_mat = matrix(runif(12, 1, 100), ncol = 3)
> dist_mat
         [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
[1,] 21.318423 89.79522 75.29824
[2,] 36.812542 18.28413 92.90719
[3,] 45.012960 89.11778 38.55608
[4,]  8.470336 46.17020 26.67135
```

On top of that, I know when the individuals were born and when the events took place, which is stored in two vectors:

```
> event_year = c(2003, 2005, 2009)
> indiv_born = c(2004, 2004, 2008, 2008)
```

My goal is to know if an individual was exposed to an event within  that took place after she was born and within, say, 30km. My solution at this point is to expand the year vectors into matrices and work it out from there, and then use `rowSums` to obtain an indicator of whether an individual was exposed to such event:

```
> event_year_m = matrix(rep(event_year, each = nrow(x1)), ncol = ncol(x1))
> indiv_born_m = matrix(rep(indiv_year, each = ncol(x1)), byrow = TRUE, ncol = ncol(x1))
> event_year_m
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] 2003 2005 2009
[2,] 2003 2005 2009
[3,] 2003 2005 2009
[4,] 2003 2005 2009
> indiv_year_m
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] 2004 2004 2004
[2,] 2004 2004 2004
[3,] 2008 2008 2008
[4,] 2008 2008 2008

> dist_mat[event_year_m < indiv_year_m] = NA
> dist_mat[dist_mat < 30] = 1
> dist_mat[dist_mat >= 30] = 0
> dist_mat
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   NA    0    0
[2,]   NA    1    0
[3,]   NA   NA    0
[4,]   NA   NA    1

> indiv_exposure = rowSums(dist_mat, na.rm = TRUE)
[1] 0 1 0 1
```

Does this make sense? Isn't there a simpler way to do this? Having only one vector would be simpler, but can't figure it out in the case of row- and column-specific thresholds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do this in a single line (or split into 2 lines for visibility) with using `col/row` for replication of 'event_year', and 'indiv_born', change the logical vector to `NA` when the 'event_year' is less than 'indiv_born', multiply with `dist_mat` so that `NA` remains NA, convert to a logical matrix with `< 30` and get the `rowSums`

```
rowSums((dist_mat * NA^(event_year[col(dist_mat)] < 
             indiv_born[row(dist_mat)])) < 30, na.rm = TRUE)
```